# pkg_resources DeprecationWarning when running pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I am working on a Python library and I recently wanted to integrate `pytest` into my development workflow. I tried running a simple test that passed, but I got a warning:

```
.venv\Lib\site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py:25
  D:\dev\python\physiscript\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py:25: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
    from pkg_resources import resource_stream, resource_exists

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
```

From the warning message, it seems that this warning is coming from `pygame` which I use in my project (`pygame-ce` actually). However, when I run my app, I don't see this warning, and I never got this warning when working with `pygame` before. Here's the sample test:

```py
# Implicitly imports pygame for other library functionality, and thus trigger the warning
import mylib


# sample test
def test_demo():
    assert True
```

The library's `__init__.py`:

```py
import pygame

def print_version():
    print(pygame.version.ver)
```

When I use the library normally, there is no warning and no problem:

```py
import mylib

mylib.print_version()
```

Can somebody explain why I get this warning with `pytest`, but not when I run the app normally?